# How to change the size of point and line at the same time but independently in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Genotype<-rep(c("GenotypeA","GenotypeB"),each=6)
Nitrogen<- rep(c(0,20,50,100,150,200),2)
Yield<- c(25,27,26,27,30,35,10,12,14,16,18,20)
dataA<- data.frame(Genotype,Nitrogen,Yield)
```

This is the data I have, and I made a line graph.

```
ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x=Nitrogen, y=Yield, fill=Genotype, shape=Genotype))+
  geom_line(aes(size=Genotype, color=Genotype)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=Genotype)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values= c(21,22)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("White", "Orange")) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(9,6))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("Red","Blue"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,200,50),limits = c(0,200)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,40,5),limits = c(0,40)) +
  labs(x="Nitrogen", y="Yield") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text (face = "plain", size = 15, color = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text (face = "plain", size = 15, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size= 15, margin = margin(t=0, r=0, b=10, l=0)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size= 15, margin = margin(t=0, r=0, b=0, l=10)),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),
        legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.key = element_rect(color = "white", fill = "white"), 
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5,"cm"),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "plain", size = 14, color = "Black"),
        legend.text = element_text(face = "plain", size = 14, color = "Black"),
        plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm")) +
  windows(width=5.5, height=5)
```

[image]

I want different line size by genotype, but due to the code `scale_size_manual(values=c(9,6))` to set up the size of point, the line size is following this code.

What I want is different line size, color and type which are independent from point size and color.

For example, 
1)line size for GenotypeA is 1 and for GenotypeB is 2.
2)line color for GenotypeA is "Green" and for GenotypeB is "Blue"
3)linetype for GenotypeA is "solid" and for GenotypeB is "dashed"

Could you tell me how to set up line formats independently from point size, or vice versa?

Many thanks,

Comment: Looks like you need the [ggnewscale](https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale) package to do this easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define them inside the manual scales with a named vector

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Data

```
Genotype<-rep(c("GenotypeA","GenotypeB"),each=6)
Nitrogen<- rep(c(0,20,50,100,150,200),2)
Yield<- c(25,27,26,27,30,35,10,12,14,16,18,20)
dataA<- data.frame(Genotype,Nitrogen,Yield)
```

### Code

```
ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x=Nitrogen, y=Yield, fill=Genotype, shape=Genotype))+
  geom_line(aes(size=Genotype, color=Genotype, linetype = Genotype)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=Genotype)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values= c(21,22)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("White", "Orange")) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c("GenotypeA" = 1,"GenotypeB" = 2))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("GenotypeA" = "Green","GenotypeB" = "Blue"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("GenotypeA" = "solid","GenotypeB" = "dashed"))
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! You're my hero!!! By the way, Is that possible to change point size and line size separately? Because the size is based on scale_size_manual(values=c("GenotypeA" = 1,"GenotypeB" = 2)), which is the same code for both point and size. I'd like to know how to change separately.